# Tracking the Size of Individual Divs, Making it Fluid

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluid-layout

In this framework I'm building, the JavaScript outputs a div block to the screen and uses a "rowTracker" in order to make sure to put the next div onto the next line once the screen cuts it off.

The next step I'd like to take is to track the size of each individual div, and have the divs rearrange once the screen width resizes. It currently rearranges after refreshing the page.

```js
width = 200;    
height = 200;
gutter = 20;

rowTracker = new Array();
heightTracker = new Array();
widthTracker = new Array();

pageWidth = 0;


$(document).ready(function(){

    pageWidth = $(document).width();    // Assign pageWidth to document page width

    counter = 0;    // Sets first counter
    counter2 = 0;   // Sets second counter
    $("section.neo__content div").each(function(index,element){ // Loops or iterates for each div
        if(((counter + 1) * (width+gutter)) < pageWidth){   // If width + gutter of div is less than width of page
            $(this).css({"top":(1 * ( (rowTracker[counter]?rowTracker[counter]:0) + gutter)),"left":(counter * (width+gutter))});   // Places div into proper position depending on page width and 20px gutter
            rowTracker[counter] = ( (rowTracker[counter]?rowTracker[counter]:0) + $(this).height() + gutter);   // Row tracker, array of counter 
            heightTracker[counter] = ($(this).height());    // Gets height of div   
            widthTracker[counter] = ($(this).width());  // Gets width of div
            counter++;  // Increment counter for each div
        }else{  // If not, run this
            console.log(rowTracker);    // Outputs heights of each row to console 
            console.log(heightTracker);
            console.log(widthTracker);
            counter = 0;    // Reset counter
            counter2++; // Second counter iterates throughout loop
            $(this).css({"top":(1 * ((rowTracker[counter]?rowTracker[counter]:0) + gutter)),"left":(counter * (width+gutter))});
            rowTracker[counter] = ( (rowTracker[counter]?rowTracker[counter]:0) + $(this).height() + gutter);
            counter++;
        }
    });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
section.neo__content {
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
section.neo__content div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
}
section.neo__content div:nth-child(3),
section.neo__content div:nth-child(12) {
  height: 350px;
}
header,
footer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
footer {
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section class="neo__content  js_content">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I hope you're aware that there are plugins that do this already...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry

Comment: See, for example, http://www.jonathanschmid.de/ext/fluid-isotope/ (resize your browser once it has loaded)

Comment: This would definitely help with another project I'm working on thank you, but I'm trying to avoid plugins for this one

Comment: The reason your fiddle didn't work is because you didn't tell it to include jQuery. I've changed your code to run directly in SO.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but can't your flow blocks be CSS inline-block, and then just capture the window resize event, grab the width of their container and resize as necessary?